# Removing all instances of object from a complex data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm writing a simple entity manager for an entity-component system for a small game framework.  My entity manager class handles components (simple data store objects) assigned to entities (a simple final object with nothing more than an ID property).  It also handles tags and group (as strings) associated with these entities.

I have the data listed in the following way:

```
private Map<String, Entity> tags = new HashMap<String, Entity>();

private Map<String, List<Entity>> groups = new HashMap<String, List<Entity>>();

private Map<Class<? extends Component>, Map<Entity, Component>> components = new HashMap<Class<? extends Component>, Map<Entity, Component>>();
```

This way I can retrieve all entities with a certain `type` of component from the hash map  very quickly.  The same goes for the other two.

The problem is that I want to be able to remove an entity completely from the system (and possibly also be able to check when the entity has no more references here, so it may be returned to a pool), but I don't know how to do that without iterating through all three structures.

```
// find if entity is in a group
for (List<Entity> entity : groups.values()) {
    if (entity.contains(e)) return true;
}

return false;
```

```
// even more complex, find if entity has any behaviors
for (Map<Entity, Component> entry : components.values()) {
    if (entry.keySet().contains(entity)) return true;
}

return false;
```

Is there a better structure I could be using that wouldn't sacrifice look-up speed, or a way to add another structure to easily check if an entity has no references in the above structures?

I don't want to add anything to the entity class, as it should contain no data itself.

EDIT: To clear up a little confusion, I also want to be able to remove a component from an entity, and if that was the only reference to a single entity, I want to remove it.  **But I can't tell if there any references to an entity without going through all three structures linearly**.

Comment: I would start with renaming `entity` into `groupEntities` in this code: `List<Entity> entity : groups.values()`

Comment: Another option is to keep lists of entity references when they're inserted/added to the structures. Basically you're re-writing GC, so the same strategies would apply.

Comment: One alternative would be to add a member variable `active` which you can set to false on deletion. Your code can then check for `isActive`. Not very pretty, but just an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can try keeping a data structure mapping each entity to the List and Map structures containing it:

```
Map<Entity,List<List<Entity>> activeLists;
// delete function
for (List<Entity> x : activeLists.get(entity))
{
   x.remove(entity);
}
```

Another idea is to use a more general graph data structure where nodes can be Entities, Groups, Tags, whatever. Then removing an entity completely is just deleting it's node in the graph; If you want to query what groups an entity belongs to, you just iterate over its edges looking for edges to groups.